# Why does this React/ReactRouter/CSS Transition only work sometimes

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create a transition between two routes.  My CSS Transition does not seem to work every time, only sporadically.  I found this post [React css transition does not work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671107/react-css-transition-does-not-work-correctly) which talks about the animation being cut off, but I don't really understand if this would apply for me.

Here is a code-pen of the issue.  Right now the transition rarely runs.  I am trying to get it to run every time you click the link.

https://codepen.io/rhigdon-the-vuer/pen/jOqEdWO

```
  <div>Code a bit too complex to post here. Let me know if it would be helpful.</div>
```

My current theory is a re-render canceling out the transition.

Update:
I ended up using the animation css property that was suggested in the comments.  This seems to work much better.  It now will reliably play the animation.

Here is the updated pen:
https://codepen.io/rhigdon-the-vuer/pen/mdPJBGv?editors=0110

Comment: https://github.com/monzoor/ayouth/blob/master/website/src/Components/Layout/Public/PublicLayout.js

check this code it might help you. Wrap your child component with animation it will work.

Comment: if you click too often in order to test it, it will not work all the times. the transition needs 1 second so If you need to test it reduce it to 0.2s for example and it will work (at least much more times depending on how quickly you click it)

Comment: @rhigdon please check my answer

Comment: I actually get an error when I visit your codesandbox.  I understand your answer and will try it out.  Going to upvote, but want to think more about it before I accept as the actual answer I am looking for.  These comments definitely are great work-arounds, but I am a little bit interested as to why the transition CSS property is doing this.

Comment: hmm just saved it again (although it didnt show me unsaved files). now it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps you but I altered your code in order to work with refs and pure css value setting and it seems to be working without problems.

Check this sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-bush-mhtby

Tricky part

```
if (divEl && divEl.current.style.width === "100%") {
  setTimeout(function () {
    divEl.current.style.width = "0%";
  }, 5);
}
```

You need to set a minimum timeout for the browser to understand that a transition needs to happen.
I tried "quick"-clicking the links and not one time did the transition not show up.